# PHP Not Fetching Table Row Data, Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Can anyone help me out?
I want to display complete mysql database table result, but getting error:

**We are connected.**

*Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fetch.php on line 28*

````
    $connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3307','root','','loginapp');
    if($connection){

        echo "We are connected.";
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

    mysqli_query($connection,$query);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Display</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-6">

<?php while($result = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){

        print_r($result);
    } ?>


  </div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>  ```
````

Comment: `$query` is the string that you sent to the database. You never assign the results of [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to a variable to use.

Comment: you have not assing this in any variable 

 mysqli_query($connection,$query);

You should assign this in variable and use that

$result =  mysqli_query($connection,$query);
use result variable in  while($result = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

Comment: Thanks Allot, Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pass query direct in mysqli_fetch_row() function you should pass mysql query

mysqli_query($connection,$query); to  $querynew =  mysqli_query($connection,$query); and use  $querynew in while($result = mysqli_fetch_row($querynew)){

like the following

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3307','root','','loginapp');
        if($connection){

            echo "We are connected.";
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

        $querynew = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        while($result = mysqli_fetch_row($querynew)){

            print_r($result);
        }
```

Comment: look at the mysqli_fetch_row and which variable he uses

Comment: This will lead to the same error, when there is at least one row.

Comment: @SanadQazi  check my answer now

Comment: @SanadQazi did you get it??